# Push Notification to multiple devices at once

Tags: push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am looking for some input on what might be a solution to the case where I will have to send a push notification to many devices at once.  The notification will retain the same message for every device that it is sent to.  I have looked into AWS SNS, but I was unable to find anything on the idea of subscribing multiple devices to one topic, or if this is a possibility?  If not, another solution to this problem would be to loop through n device tokens which might not be the most efficient way of doing so.

If you have any other recommendations, they would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By right IPA should cater this, currently one of my apps is able to send a push notification to multiple device based on their token key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firebase Cloud Messaging** provides the feature that you are looking for
under the name of `Topic Messaging`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

In you app you can subscribe for a `topic`:

**Android**:  `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");`
**iOS**: `[[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/news"];`

Then **your server** can send a message to all the devices:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you, I will give this a go tonight.  My only issue might be if there is a max cap off to the amount of topics that I will be allowed to create.  Really appreciate your input, I'll keep you posted as to how this makes out.